# Is a question that can be found on google allowed?

Tags: discussion, site-definition

From my friend @BeatMe [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1824723#1824723) asked "So a question that is easily googleable (top 5 links for the exact question give a huge selection of answers) shouldn't be answered?"

Right after commenting on my question [Who are the two witnesses in the book of Revelation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1677/who-are-the-two-witnesses-in-the-book-of-revelation)

My question is the same, where do we draw the line with questions and google?

Comment: I don't think this has so much to do with googleability as it does with the value added content aspect of this site. Se here for revelation discussion: [Answers copied from an external source](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/154)

Comment: I told my fingers to type "relevant" but then my brain got distracted reading the copy of the question again and they parroted "revelation".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The canonical flowchart for whether a question should be answered or closed as *off-topic*  is featured in the blog post "[Are Some Questions Too Simple?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/)":

[image: Too Simple Flowchart]

#### If you do a web search for the question is the answer in the first few results?

[Yes, it is.](http://www.google.com/search?cx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Who+are+the+two+witnesses+in+the+book+of+Revelation%3F)

#### Is the answer too slow to load, too hard to parse, or otherwise in need of improvement?

The [first hit](http://www.letusreason.org/Biblexp50.htm), while not from a canonical source, was quick to load and provided a great, easy to read overview of the possible candidates. If you don't like that answer, the [Wikipedia article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_witnesses) is the 4th hit, and is what was quoted as an answer.

#### Is the question basic, trivial, or is it complex and interesting for experts?

This is a toss-up. While it's an interesting question for experts (and there is no shortage of writings about the subject), if it's wholly answered by an excerpt from Wikipedia, I would consider it to be trivial.

So I'd consider this question borderline, and one of the cases where the *answers*, not the question content, [determine if the question is viable here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/855/what-are-the-rules-around-moderators-closing-questions-outright/862#862). If I had to choose, I'd say the answer quoting Wikipedia should be deleted and see what answers come in.

Answer (score 3):

After googling ( :D ) about "stackexchange, google and easy question", I found [this blogpost of Jeff Atwood](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) that indicates: "**it depends**".

So I answered the mentioned question with a quote.

Comment: Answered it with a quote and got your butt handed to you with downvotes.

Comment: It's still the single best answer we got ;)

Comment: That's certainly true!